# Eclipse screws up every time I type an object's method

Tags: java, eclipse

So for example with my current object tabPanelMain, I'll type a dot after it and expect to see a drop down menu of all the object's available methods. Instead, the marker which shows my currently selected character on the editor disappears meaning I don't know where I'm typing. Worse than that is that the save and save all buttons stop working. And ctrl-s and the menu saves don't work either. I can't save my eclipse projects and have to restart, thus losing my work.

What could be wrong? This problem never used to exist but now I just can't get the methods of an object like I used to.

I hope that was clear enough, please ask me questions if not.

Comment: Have you tried restarting eclipse, etcetera?

Comment: which eclipse? What platform? Did you change anything? any settings? Have you tried re-installing, updating it?

Comment: The only work around I've just found is switching to another opened class. For some reason this makes the save buttons work again. Still can't see a list of an object's available methods though.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Indigo with some subclipse and GWT plugins

Comment: I'm probably gonna try a re-install. Including all my plugins unless pasting the old folder in works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out what it was that was causing the problem, and while Martin Larsson provided an effective short term solution, I found it best to fresh install Eclipse.

The most annoying part about this was transferring my previous plug ins (like GWT, Subversion, etc) over to the new install. In the end I ended up re-installing them manually. If anyone could shed some light on how to keep previous plug ins, I'd like to hear how. Though I've heard this can be problematic with path urls in the files or something.

Answer (score 1):

The save problem with not being able to save is one I've encountered before.

I don't know why it happens but for me it helps to minimize and then maximize eclipse again.
Not a fix but at least a workaround that lets you save.

Never heard of the other problem though.

Comment: For me a workaround is switching to another running application and then switching back to Eclipse. Seems like the changes of the foreground application "restore" the normal save behaviour.